# How to convert already encoded string representation of Bytes Array to actualy Bytes Array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, compression

The problem: We had a system that events and projections had a column Payload which is a serialized object. This payload was a string but for performance and saving disk space considerations we started saving a compressed version of the string in the database. and we decompress it whenever fetching from the Database.

Code for compressing and decompressing

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

namespace DemoEFCore.Helpers
{
    public class CompressionHelper
    {
        public static byte[] Compress(string stringData)
        {
            var stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData);
            
            using var output = new MemoryStream();
            using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
            {
                dstream.Write(stringBytes, 0, stringBytes.Length);
            }
            return output.ToArray();
        }

        public static string Decompress(byte[] data)
        {
            using var input = new MemoryStream(data);
            using var output = new MemoryStream();
            using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                dstream.CopyTo(output);
            }
            var bytes = output.ToArray();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        }

    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine and it really gives performance improvements.

But sometimes when you are fixing a bug you go straight to the database to see a payload of a concrete record. I could copy it and paste in some of the JSON beautifier previously but now I can copy only encoded representation.

[screenshot from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiMnZ.png)

```
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
```

What we want to do is to have the ability to copy this string, paste it in our application and get the decoded JSON string. It sounds easy because we already have the `CompressionHelper.Decompress` method but it accepts a bytes array as a parameter. I found 3 solutions on how I can convert such a string to a bytes array but they didn't work for me.

1.

```
    var s = "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
            
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(s);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
var s1 = CompressionHelper.Decompress(stream.ToArray());
```

The line `var s1 = CompressionHeplepr.Decompress(stream.ToArray());` throws exception `System.IO.InvalidDataException: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.`

2.

```
var s = "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
        
        var b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
        var jsonString = CompressionHelper.Decompress(b);
```

The line `var b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);` throws this exception `System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.`

3.

```
        try
        {
            var s = "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
            //var substring = s.Substring(2);
        
            var byteArray = new byte[s.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                var b = Byte.Parse(s[i].ToString());
                byteArray[i] = b;
            }
        
            var jsonString = CompressionHelper.Decompress(byteArray);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
```

throws this exception

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.Byte.Parse(String s)
```

Can you please help me to figure out how to solve my problem?

Comment: From a cursory glance, the second thing you tried wouldn't have worked because you don't have a base 64 string, you have a hexadecimal string. There's a [Convert.FromHexString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.fromhexstring?view=net-5.0) method that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

@madmonk46 Thank You indeed. [Convert.FromHexString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.fromhexstring?view=net-5.0) really helped. I couldn't find this method at first because my demo project is on .NET Core 3.1 but Convert.FromHexString supported starting from .NET 5. luckily our project is on .NET 5 and we are migrating to .NET6 now))

Also it is not working with string that starts from 0x.

```
var stringFromDataBase = "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
var bytesArray = Convert.FromHexString(stringFromDataBase);
var jsonString = CompressionHelper.Decompress(bytesArray);
```

this code throws

```
System.FormatException: The input is not a valid hex string as it contains a non-hex character.
```

so you need to add one line of code to it.

```
var stringFromDataBase = "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
var substring = stringFromDataBase.Substring(2);
var bytesArray = Convert.FromHexString(substring);
var jsonString = CompressionHelper.Decompress(bytesArray);
```

[image: result]

Thank you one more time for your quick help, madmonk46!